# HTML page with simple embedded php not displaying any content

Tags: php, html, css

I have a very simple webpage I am developing locally on my Mac OS X Leopard. I just recently connected PHP 5.2.15 to my Apache server, and after storing the following html file in the proper Root directory (equivalent to localhost), when I load the file in Firefox 15.0.1 and go to localhost the title of the page is properly displayed but none of the rest of the HTML content or the PHP echo statements are displayed, which is weird because when I go to the same address in Chrome all of the HTML and CSS content are properly interpreted but the php echo statements are not displayed. Is this a cache issue? Is there a special procedure I have to do when I make edits to index.html and save them back to the root directory?

Here is the HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title> My Page </title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="basic.css">
</head>
<body>
<p> Some text. </p>
<?php
    echo "Hey this is PHP talking.";
    echo "Is anybody there?";
?>
<p> More Text. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

And Here is the basic.css family:

```
p {font-family:"Avantgarde"; font-size: xx-large; color: white; letter-spacing:3px}
body {background: 2C75FF}
b {font-weight: normal;
   font-family:"Book Antiqua";
   font-size:75%;
   letter-spacing: normal;
  }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: **storing the following html file**. Store it as `.php` extension.

Comment: Are you sure that your extension is `.php` ?

Comment: Alternatively it is also possible to setup the webserver so the .htm/.html files are also parsed as potential PHP files.

Advantage: If you decided to make a page 'smarter' later on you do not have to change the extension, makes maintenance easier.

Disadvantage: That makes the webserver work harder since potentially all the files have to be parsed by the php interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the file extension? If it's `.html/.htm` make it `.php`.

Also, how are you running the file? Do you have a server like **WAMP** or **XAMPP** set up? If you don't PHP code won't run.

Comment: how do I see if WAMP or XAMP is set up?

Comment: Did you ever install one of them? If not please visit [link](http://www.wampserver.com) and install WAMP. After you do, move the file to wampInstallFolder/www (typically c:/wamp/www).

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by checking if phpinfo works:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Please change your script to this and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you all, it was a very amateur move...wrong file extension!

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Your Extension of File Should Be '.php' , not '.html'.Also check for your server.

Answer (score 0):

For wamp users:

Installation Directory (by default):

```
C:\wamp\www
```

Your file:

```
C:\wamp\www\sample\file.php
```

'sample' is directory name, just replace this your own directory name.

'file.php' is file name.

After Installing your local server first you have to check your local server is successfully running on your system. (If you find any problem just comment here and i will guide you.)  And after that Just simple open browser type on URL field

```
localhost\sample\file.php
```

And you see the output. Happy coading :)